# Discord.js - Creating Invite Link with Permission Attached

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am using the [createInvite](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=createInvite) function on a channel that has `VIEW_CHANNEL: false, CONNECT: false` permissions setup for the `everyone` role. Is it possible to create a channel invite that would give permission to join the channel? What I am trying to do is create a private room and send out invite links to it.

Here's my code. The invite link that is created lets users join the discord server, but not the private room.

```
    const guild = discordClient.guilds.first();
    const everyoneRole = guild.roles.find('name', '@everyone');
    const channelName = uuid();
    guild.createChannel(channelName, {
        type: "voice"
    }).then((channel) => {
        channel.overwritePermissions(everyoneRole, {
            CONNECT: false,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
        }).then(() => {
            channel.createInvite({
                channel: channelName,
            }).then((invite) => {
                resolve(invite);
            });
        });
    }).catch(reject);
```

Answer (score 1):

With false connect permission, you cant.

They 1 way its fetch servers ivites, then when member join to server, you can get his invite, and if invite === "your invite link" add him role with acces to this channel.

They [one](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites.md) way how to fetch user invite

Comment: This approach almost worked, but the `guildMemberAdd` event only fires the first time the users joins and I'd need it to fire ever time a user joins the channel from a link. I ended up giving the user a code that they send to my discord bot. The bot gives the user permission to join the channel and sends an invite link.